# In bash, can the file operator (-f) be case-insensitive?

Tags: bash, case-insensitive

I'm doing the following:

```
if [ -f $FILE ] ; then
    echo "File exists"
fi
```

But I want the `-f` to be case-insensitive. That is, if FILE is `/etc/somefile`, I want -f to recognize `/Etc/SomeFile`.

I can partially work around it with glob:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
TARG='/etc/somefile'

MATCH=$TARG*    #assume it returns only one match
 
if [[ -f $MATCH ]] ; then
    echo "File exists" 
fi
```

but the case-insensitive globbing works only on the filename portion, not the full path. So it will not work if TARG is `/Etc/somefile`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12953235/848072 for a 
thorough analysis of insensitive **find**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that your *filesystem* is case-sensitive.  The filesystem provides only two relevant ways to get a file: either you specify an exact, case-sensitive filename and check for its existence that way, or you read all the files in a directory and then check if each one matches a pattern.

In other words, it is very inefficient to check if a case-insensitive version of a file exists on a case-sensitive filesystem.  The shell might do it for you, but internally it's reading all the directory's contents and checking each one against a pattern.

Given all that, this works:

```bash
if [[ -n $(find /etc -maxdepth 1 -iname passwd) ]]; then
  echo "Found";
fi
```

BUTunless you want to search everything from '/' on down, you must check component of the path individually.  There is no way around this; you can't magically check a whole path for case-insensitive matches on a case-sensitive filesystem!

Comment: `find / -iwholename` would probably also work, but would be grossly inefficient.

Comment: @Philipp: yeah, as I said, "unless you want to search everything from '/' on down"... And if you have any circular symlinks, pray...

Comment: someone should probably tell this to debian (pkg/debian: ok; pkg/Debian: good to go!; pkg/DeBiAn: why not?!)

Comment: On a ***wholename***,  `find` could be lot too slow! Have a look at [my `ipath` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123812/1765658)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the nocasematch option

```
shopt -s nocasematch
for file in *
do
  case "$file" in
   "/etc/passWd" ) echo $file;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I don't think this works since the glob doesn't return absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

not knowing howto only using shell evaluations.
but grep can be case-insensitive, therefore a script that invokes grep , find and wc may meet your demand.

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard to do, in general, if the file system is case-sensitive. Basically, you have iterate over each of the ancestor directories separately. Here is a starting point in `Python`:

```
import os

def exists_nocase(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        return True
    path = os.path.normpath(os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(unicode(path)))).upper()
    parts = path.split(os.sep)
    path = unicode(os.path.join(unicode(os.path.splitdrive(path)[0]), os.sep))
    for name in parts:
        if not name:
            continue
        # this is a naive and insane way to do case-insensitive string comparisons:
        entries = dict((entry.upper(), entry) for entry in os.listdir(path))
        if name in entries:
            path = os.path.join(path, entries[name])
        else:
            return False
    return True

print exists_nocase("/ETC/ANYTHING")
print exists_nocase("/ETC/PASSWD")
```

Answer (score 1):

### As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

#### Introduction

I was searching for window's registry file after mounted NTFS partition in a temporary mount point `mnt=$(mktemp -d)`

Then, if the command:

```
regfile=$(find $mnt -iwholename "$mnt/window*/system32/config/software")
```

do the job, as this command is based on $mnt, `find` will stupidely scan the whole filesystem and take a **lot of time**.

#### My *pure bash* function

For this, I wrote this `ipath` function:

```
ipath() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then local -n _res=$2; shift 2; else local _res; fi
    local _path _i _chr
    _res=
    for ((_i=0;_i<${#1};_i++));do
        _chr=${1:_i:1} _chr=${_chr,}
        [[ $_chr != ${_chr^} ]] && _path+="[$_chr${_chr^}]" ||
                _path+=$_chr
    done
    _path=($_path)
    [[ -e ${_path[0]} ]] || return 1
    if [[ ${_res@A} == _res=* ]] ;then
        printf "%s\n" "${_path[@]}"
    else
        _res=("${_path[@]}")
    fi
}
```

Then for testing:

```
$ ipath "$mnt/window*/system32/config/software"
/tmp/tmp.Q2czvPDs5m/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE

$ ipath ~/desktop
/home/user/Desktop
```

for use as a *variable*:

```
$ ipath -v regfile "$mnt/window*/system32/config/software"
$ echo $regfile 
/tmp/tmp.Q2czvPDs5m/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE

$ ipath -v DeskDir ~/desktop
echo $DeskDir
/home/user/Desktop
```

Another test with multiple answer and spaced path:

```
$ ipath $mnt/program\*/int\*er
/tmp/tmp.jVs5mPGbJm/Program Files/Internet Explorer
/tmp/tmp.jVs5mPGbJm/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer

$ ipath -v iedirs "$mnt/program*/int*er"
$ declare -p iedirs
declare -a iedirs=([0]="/tmp/tmp.jVs5mPGbJm/Program Files/Internet Explorer" [1]="/tmp/tmp.jVs5mPGbJm/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer")
```

Note, tested with unicode accented characters: `résumé.pdf` become `[rR][éÉ][sS][uU][mM][éÉ].[pP][dD][fF]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /etc
# using FreeBSD find
find -x -L "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iregex "/EtC/[^\/]*" -iname paSSwd
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's a starting point using Bash:

```
#  fci -- check if file_case_insensitive exists 
# (on a case sensitive file system; complete file paths only!)

function fci() {   

declare IFS checkdirs countslashes dirpath dirs dirstmp filepath fulldirpaths i name ndirs result resulttmp

[[ -f "$1" ]] && { return 0; }
[[ "${1:0:1}" != '/' ]] && { echo "No absolute file path given: ${1}" 2>&1; return 1; }
[[ "$1" == '/' ]] && { return 1; }

filepath="$1"
filepath="${filepath%"${filepath##*[!/]}"}"  # remove trailing slashes, if any
dirpath="${filepath%/*}"
name="${filepath##*/}"

IFS='/'
dirs=( ${dirpath} )

if [[ ${#dirs[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
   fulldirpaths=( '/' )
   ndirs=1
else
   IFS=""
   dirs=( ${dirs[@]} )
   ndirs=${#dirs[@]}

   for ((i=0; i < ${ndirs}; i++)); do

      if [[ $i -eq 0 ]]; then
         checkdirs=( '/' )
      else
         checkdirs=( "${dirstmp[@]}" )
      fi

      IFS=$'\777'
      dirstmp=( $( find -x -L "${checkdirs[@]}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "${dirs[i]}" -print0 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\777' ) )

      IFS=""
      fulldirpaths=( ${fulldirpaths[@]} ${dirstmp[@]} )

   done

fi

printf "fulldirpaths: %s\n" "${fulldirpaths[@]}" | nl

for ((i=0; i < ${#fulldirpaths[@]}; i++)); do
   countslashes="${fulldirpaths[i]//[^\/]/}"
   [[ ${#countslashes} -ne ${ndirs} ]] && continue
   IFS=$'\777'
   resulttmp=( $( find -x -L "${fulldirpaths[i]}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "${name}" -print0 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\777' ) )
   IFS=""
   result=( ${result[@]} ${resulttmp[@]} )
done

IFS=""
result=( ${result[@]} )

printf "result: %s\n" "${result[@]}" | nl

if [[ ${#result[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
   return 1
else
   return 0
fi
}


FILE='/eTC/paSSwD'

if fci "${FILE}" ; then
   echo "File (case insensitive) exists: ${FILE}" 
else
   echo "File (case insensitive) does NOT exist: ${FILE}" 
fi
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123812/1765658