# Case insensitive filename search and retrieval in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, sh

I want to get hold of the readme file of github repos for further processing. The problem is that the filename could have different case like `readme.md` or `Readme.md` or `README.md` etc.

I want to find which variation of the readme file is present and also retrieve that filename in a shell variable for further processing. Also I want this script to work both in Ubuntu and mac.

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953235/24949), I found that I can use `find`

`find -ipath 'readme.md'`

But this doesn't work in mac.

Comment: `find . -name "*" | grep -i readme`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this seems like a good option. Can you kindly post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-iname` option:

```
find . -iname readme.md
#    ^
```

**UPDATE** You need to pass `path` (`.` in the above command).

---

According to [`find(1)` Mac OSX Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html):

> ```
> -iname pattern
>         Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.
> ```

Comment: `-iname` or `-ipath` option is not available in mac

Comment: @Sudar, According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), both are available.

Comment: I just tried in Mac OS maverick and it says `illegal option -i`. Not sure if things changed in Maverick

Comment: @Sudar, The documentation is for Mac OS X version 10.9 (Maverick). What is the output of `which find` ? (to check which `find` program you are using)

Comment: Output of `which find` is `/usr/bin/find`

Comment: Ah... Did you pass the path to find? I updated the answer to include `.`. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash's "nocaseglob", like this:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

Here is an example of how it works:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob 
echo hi > ReAdMe 
more README
hi
more readme
hi
more rEaD*
hi
```